# How do I assign an INT from comboboxes to add them and display result in textbox1

Tags: c#, combobox, int, var

I am trying to have a dynamic set of comboboxes that change based on the last selection. However, I want them to create a custom string of numbers for each possible outcome. When I would like is to have each one add a value of 1s, 10s, 100s, and 1000s.

(for example selection the first option in each combobox would display 1111 in the textbox2 or if they select the second option in combobox1 then the first for the rest it would display 1112) here is the code below:

Essentially I just want to add values that are created based on the selection from each combobox in textbox2 and have them display.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox2.Items.Add("1");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("2");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("3");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("4");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox2.Items.Add("1");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("2");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("3");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("4");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox2.Items.Add("5");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("6");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("7");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("8");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Corp Over 250k");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Corp Under 250k");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Hybrid Over 250k");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Hybrid Under 250k");
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox2.Items.Add("1");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("2");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("3");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("4");
        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Add("Move Amendment Override");
        }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Add("Move Ammendment Override INTERNAL");
        }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Add("250 - 399");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("400 - 599");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("600 - 799");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("800 - 999");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("1000 - 1499");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("1500 - 1999");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("2000+");
        }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Add("Move Hybrid Documents");
        }
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the problem.  Are you getting an error with the code above?  If so what?  If not, what part is not working as intended?

Comment: I am not getting an error yes. However, if I add                                                                                                                     else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            var sub1 = 1;                                                                                                                       }                                                                                                                 I get something that tells me that sub1 is not available in the context

Comment: if you declare `sub1` inside an if statement, its scope is only available inside the if statement.  It cannot be used outside the braces.

Comment: so do I just make one super long if statement that first determines the strings displayed (which it does now) then a second if statement under the same rule that adds a value to textbox2? if so, how would that look?

Comment: why do you have `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)` 3 times doing the same thing?

Comment: this way the next combobox can dynamically change the available values based on the selection of combobox1

Comment: oh I see what you are saying, there is a redundant string of If statements. I removed it. the Debug didnt notice it and neither did i haha. but that wasnt causing any issues.

Comment: it should only have one of those sections, not 3. I removed the extra ones. I must have copied them over from another section and missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, these items would be populated by some external source, like a database.  However, as you are hard-coding the values in each drop down, I suggest you populate the textbox like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Dictionary<int, string[]> comboBox1Options = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
      comboBox1Options.Add(0, new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" });

      comboBox1.Items.Clear();
      comboBox1.Items.AddRange(comboBox1Options[0]);

    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Dictionary<int, string[]> comboBox2Options = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
      comboBox2Options.Add(0, new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" });
      comboBox2Options.Add(1, new[] { "5", "6", "7", "8" });
      comboBox2Options.Add(2, new[] { "Corp Over 250k", "Corp Under 250k", "Hybrid Over 250k", "Hybrid Under 250k" });

      comboBox2.Items.Clear();
      comboBox2.Items.AddRange(comboBox2Options[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);
      textBox2.Text = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Dictionary<int, string[]> comboBox3Options = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
      comboBox3Options.Add(0, new[] { "Move Amendment Override" });
      comboBox3Options.Add(1, new[] { "Move Ammendment Override INTERNAL" });
      comboBox3Options.Add(2, new[] { "250 - 399", "400 - 599", "600 - 799", "800 - 999" });
      comboBox3Options.Add(3, new[] { "Move Hybrid Documents" });

      comboBox3.Items.Clear();
      comboBox3.Items.AddRange(comboBox3Options[comboBox2.SelectedIndex]);
      textBox2.Text += comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      textBox2.Text += comboBox3.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, using a dictionary instead of many if statements drastically simplifies your code.